# How to disable access to sandbox to one user in sfdc

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I am new to sfdc. We have two administrators In my organisation and we have only one developer sandbox is available.I refreshed that sandbox few-days back Before refresh the sandbox it is used by other administrator with different credentials.I refresh the sandbox with my credentials in production org.So, i got new credentials with sandbox login Both credentials are accepting in sandbox.So, my problem is back-end team needs sandbox now.so,which credentials i have to gave it back end team.Is there any way to disable one user credentials for sandbox login.In my previous company i always work in single sandbox.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: disable the user.

Comment: But he is adminstrator @Tushar Sharma..

Comment: you can disable the admin. Unless the account is not registered with his email address(he is not primary user).

Comment: Is there any problem if you continue using sandbox with two users @Tushar Sharma

Comment: no in SB we have multiple users.

Comment: Thanks so,it means a single box can be used by multiple users @Tushar Sharma.

Comment: Couldn't you just freeze the accounts you don't want to access the Sandbox?

Comment: Once you're in the sandbox, you can remove that user's account or freeze it from within the sandbox itself. Once you do that, he shouldn't be able to login to that sandbox.